# proving a sequence converge in distribution

Tags: probability

I'm stuck with the following problem:

Let $\{\xi_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of random variables taking values in $[0,1]$. Assume for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}E(\xi_n^k)=\frac{1}{k+1}$. Then $\{\xi_n\}$ converges in distribution.

It looks like the limit $\xi$ should be uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$, so I tried to use $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}E(\xi_n^k-\xi^k)=0$ for all $k$ for proving it converges in probability but it didn't work. Could I ask for a hint? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $\{\xi_n\}$ is bounded by $0$ and $1$, for every $n$, $\xi_n$ has every order moment, thus the characteristic function of $\xi_n$ can be written as 
$$\varphi_n(t) = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{(it)^k}{k!}E(\xi_n^k)$$ 
It follows by bounded convergence theorem and condition that
$$\varphi_n(t) \to \sum_{k = 0}^\infty\frac{(it)^k}{k!}\frac{1}{k + 1} = \frac{e^{it} - 1}{it}$$
as $n \to \infty$. Note the limit is the characteristic function of uniform distribution, by continuity theorem, $\xi_n$ converges in distribution to $\xi$, where $\xi \sim \text{U}(0, 1)$.